# Making the progress bar of a sound-playback element stay visible

Tags: audio, microsoft-powerpoint

In one of my slides I have a sound-playback element, and while the sound is playing I'd like the audience to keep seeing the time/progress bar that is shown when one first presses Play, so they can see how much longer the sound goes on for:
[image]

Unfortunately, this bar seems to disappear after a few seconds, until the mouse is moved, and hovering the mouse above the playback-control-area, or right-clicking, doesn't help.

I've searched solutions online but found none. Thanks in advance for any suggestions/workarounds!

Comment: You asked this question on [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/making-the-progress-bar-of-a-sound-playback/bf773580-676b-4fc6-92f9-bdedcc35f527) and got a correct negative answer that no solution exists in PowerPoint. In fact, only moving the mouse over the icon makes it appear. It's possible for an outside program to continuously move the mouse to make the bar stay on the screen, but would you call it a good solution?

Comment: Receiving a "correct negative answer" does not mean that other workarounds cannot be thought up. It's plausible someone has faced the same challenge and (accidentally) stumbled upon a solution, and it's that kind of contribution I was hoping for here.

Comment: I don't think you will find another workaround than faking mouse movement.

Comment: I don't think you can postulate that no other workaround can be found, @harrymc ;) By definition these are solutions that no-one planned to have working, but that nonetheless arrive at the intended behaviour. It could be inserting some other element that by accident makes the playback controls stay visible, or something like that. I'll keep the bounty open to reap any crowd-sourcing wisdom that way, if that's ok with you ;)

Comment: This was just an opinion, not a verdict. I think that a mouse-faking program is easy to write, so I'm a bit surprised that you reject it out of hand.

Comment: sorry I don't mean to say I am rejecting that option, just waiting to see if other workarounds are suggested based on the kind of "happy coincidences/bugs" I metioned. I found several of those myself by accident so I wouldnt be surprised if smth like this existed in this case also

Comment: Being pessimistic, I don't usually expect happy surprises from PowerPoint. So I added below an AutoHotkey script that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script will activate upon
pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>. It will move the cursor forward by one pixel then
back to the initial position. It will stop moving the cursor upon a second press
of <kbd>F12</kbd> or if the cursor is moved manually
or if the active window changes.

Copy the following into an `.ahk` file, possibly changing "F12".
Double-click the file to start it executing. It will create a green "H"
icon in the traybar that you can right-click and select `Exit` to stop.
If you always want this script to execute, copy it to the user Startup folder at
`C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Window

X := -1
Y := -1
WIN =
Running := false

F12::
if Running {
  Running := false
  SetTimer, FakeMouseMove, Off
} else {
  Running := true
  MouseGetPos, X, Y, WIN
  SetTimer, FakeMouseMove, 500
}
return

FakeMouseMove:
MouseGetPos, X1, Y1, WIN1
newX := X + 1
if ((X1 != X and X1 != newX) or Y != Y1 or WIN != WIN1) {
  SetTimer, FakeMouseMove, Off
  Running := false
} else {
  DoMouseMove(X, Y)
  Sleep, 100
  DoMouseMove(newX, Y)
}
return

DoMouseMove(X, Y) {
  MouseMove, %X%, %Y%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Approach # 1:**

Since Microsoft doesn't have a real solution, you'll probably have to work with a mouse movement program. I have used ["Mouse Jiggler"](https://github.com/cerebrate/mousejiggler/releases) for this and other tasks like it, though solution in AHK or AutoIT could be made pretty easily as well. It's a simple program that moves the mouse on a short interval, and includes a "zen mode" that spoofs mouse input without actually moving the cursor. It is portable too so it can be used on computers for which you don't have installation privileges.

**Approach # 2:**

Since you can't use the timer that is built in, create your own timer that matches the length of the audio file and display it while the audio file runs.

There are many methods that allow you to accomplish this if you make your own.  [Tekhnologic provides several methods on their website,]. However, I like simpler methods myself, such as using the free [PP Timer plugin](https://www.pp-timer.com/) or using an embedded video timer. You can use [video timers found on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=timer), you can use existing video timer creation software [(such as the free one found on countingdownto)](https://countingdownto.com/) or you can record your own timer with screen capture software to get a really specific time interval.

Comment: Tried it - Zen mode doesn't work with PowerPoint. This is a very old product.

Comment: It's not old if you download from the source (which I finally found and updated the link). At any rate, the jiggling idea certainly works without zen mode enabled, and does the same thing as the AHK script in harrymc's solution. If you want this to work for clients viewing the presentation themselves (ie, while you aren't there), this is an entirely different question. I will make a separate answer for a possible workaround.

Comment: @z8080 My second solution is much more automated than the first and works without jiggling any mice. =)

Comment: Thank you, I will also give this a try!